# pgfplot log-log plot: Axes Exponents

Tags: pgfplots

I have a question about formatting the axes using `pgfplots` in LaTeX. For some reason the exponents in my log-log plots (base 10) are fractions instead of whole numbers, i.e. instead of having `10^1, 10^2, 10^3, ...` it is `10^1.1, 10^1.2, 10^1.3`.

How do I get whole numbers instead of fractions as exponents?

Comment: Your axis range is probably just too small. You can set `ytickten={0,...,10}` to limit the ticks to integer exponents, but you'll probably end up with only one tick mark (no way of telling without a complete example, though).

Comment: @Jake I suppose you can use your comment as answer.

Comment: @Jake Would you like to answer, or close as unclear?